# What kind of errors set "errno" to non-zero? Why does fopen() set "errno" while fputc() does not?

Tags: c, fopen, errno, fputcsv

What kind of errors faced by what kind of library functions affect the **errno** and set it to non-zero value? In my following program, I intended to use `if(errno!=0)` as a condition to check if the library functions I used functioned properly or not, and this is what I found (see the code below):

First I used `if(errno!=0)` to test if a file has been opened successfully with `fopen()` or not. If I try to open a non-existent file, then `errno` is set to non-zero (2 in my case) and it is verified by printing out the value of `errno` at each stage. But if I open an existing file, then the value of errno remains zero as `fopen()` opens the file properly. In this matter,`if(errno!=0)` acts as the perfect substitute to `if(pFile==NULL)` which I have commented out.

If the file is opened successfully, with `errno` still `0`, the control moves to the first `else` block. This is where I find confusions about the behavior of `errno`. Here, since I have opened the file in **r(read)** mode and attempting to write to it using `fputc()`, I expect the resulting write-error to set `errno` to non-zero just as it is set by `fopen()` when it couldn't open the file successfully. But the value of `errno` continues to be zero even after that unsuccessful write using `fputc()`. (This is verifiable by printing value of `errno` after the faulty write).

Why is it so? Why is I/O error faced by one function `fopen()` setting the `errno` while write error faced by other function `fputc()` not affecting `errno`? If it's so, how can we reliably use `errno` as an indicator of error? **Is my use of errno to test if fopen() worked successfully, instead of "if(pFile==NULL)" unwise?** I will appreciate your analytic answers to this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main ()
{

  FILE * pFile;
  printf("%d\n",errno);

  pFile = fopen("D:\\decrypt.txt","r");
  printf("%d\n",errno); // Prints 0 if fopen() successful,else 2

  //if(pFile==NULL) perror("Error opening file"); 

   if (errno!=0) perror ("Error opening file");

  else
  {
    fputc ('x',pFile);
     printf("%d\n",errno); //errno shows 0 even after write error

     //if (ferror (pFile))
    if (errno!=0)  //Condition evaluates false even if faulty write
      {
      printf ("Error Writing to decrypt.txt\n"); 
        }
    fclose (pFile);

  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: [POSIX says:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) "The value of errno should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value."

Comment: @Mat What does C-standard say?And what is meant by `..when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value.`?Can you put it in an answer with more details please?

Comment: [Where can I see the list of functions that interact with errno?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116602/where-can-i-see-the-list-of-functions-that-interact-with-errno)

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Check out the link for more answers. Not every library function sets errno. C standard doesn't say which functions set errno and even setting errno is not necessarily an actual error.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: hmjd already quoted the C standard.

Comment: @Mat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507974/can-or-cant-errno-be-set-to-zero-by-a-library-function-user-functionive-con

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation largely tells you which function can set which values in `errno`, but there are some rules you need to know:

1. No library function sets `errno` to zero.
2. It is only valid to test `errno` when the function has indicated that an error has occurred (and the function is documented to set `errno`).

The first point means that if you want to know whether, for example, you've gotten an error from [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html), you have to set `errno` to 0 before calling it.

The second point is crucial; for example, on Solaris, after many I/O operations when the channel was not a terminal, the setting of `errno` would be `ENOTTY` (not a terminal).  There wasn't an error; nothing had failed; but basing your subsequent actions on `errno` alone (and not on the status reported by the I/O operation) would lead you to think everything failed.

Thus, in your code, the `fopen()` call may leave `errno` as a non-zero value, even though it successfully creates the file stream.  You have to use:

```
const char filename[] = "D:\\crypt.txt";
if ((pFile = fopen(filename, "r")) == 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading (%d: %s)\n",
            filename, errno, strerror(errno));
    ...return or exit...
}
```

Beware: if you need to call a function that can alter `errno`, capture the value early:

```
    int errnum = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for reading (%d: %s)\n",
            filename, errnum, strerror(errnum));
```

And never declare `errno` yourself; always use `#include <errno.h>` to do it.

I'm not clear why your code is not getting an error on the `fputc()` call.  On my Mac OS X 10.8.3 system, the equivalent code fails with `errno` set to 9 (EBADF) 'Bad file descriptor'.

---

Where is this documented?  It's in the C standard, and reinforced by the POSIX standard.

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`

> ¶3 The value of `errno` in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of `errno` in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is never set to zero by any library function.<sup>202)</sup> The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard.
>
> <sup>202)</sup> Thus, a program that uses `errno` for error checking should set it to zero before a library function call, then inspect it before a subsequent library function call. Of course, a library function can save the value of `errno` on entry and then set it to zero, as long as the original value is restored if `errno`’s value is still zero just before the return.

The wording in previous versions of the C standard did not mention threads but was otherwise similar.

Note that the description of `fopen()` in the C standard does not mention `errno`.  Therefore, it is permitted to set `errno` by the C standard.  By contrast, the `mbsrtowcs()` function is documented to set `errno` to EILSEQ; it probably can't set it to other values because the C standard says it shouldn't (though there's nothing much to stop an implementation from doing so if it has a better error for some condition).

#### POSIX 2008

The POSIX page for [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) says:

> Many functions provide an error number in `errno`, which has type `int` and is defined in `<errno.h>`. The value of `errno` shall be defined only after a call to a function for which it is explicitly stated to be set and until it is changed by the next function call or if the application assigns it a value. The value of `errno` should only be examined when it is indicated to be valid by a function's return value. Applications shall obtain the definition of `errno` by the inclusion of `<errno.h>`. No function in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall set `errno` to 0. The setting of `errno` after a successful call to a function is unspecified unless the description of that function specifies that `errno` shall not be modified.
>
> It is unspecified whether `errno` is a macro or an identifier declared with external linkage. If a macro definition is suppressed in order to access an actual object, or a program defines an identifier with the name `errno`, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The symbolic values stored in errno are documented in the ERRORS sections on all relevant pages.

The wording in previous versions was similar.

Comment: Concerning the specific failure of fputc in the question, Rüppell is on Windows. [fputc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah67377(v=vs.80).aspx) from the Windows CRT isn't documented to set errno for this type of problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can you take a second to tell me what about `hacking the file names`?I am alien to the world of linux.Do you mean file paths have a different format than windows?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And I am such a wretched fellow I first read Windows CRT as "Windows Cathode Ray Tube".That's the only CRT I knew before I smelled a rat and googled it to find it's Windows C Runtime Library after all.

Comment: Pathnames on Unix use slash as a separator instead of backslash, and absolute names start with `/`.  There are no drives as on Windows.  Hence `/bin/sh` is an absolute pathname, and `abc/def` is a relative pathname.  On Windows, you can use slash instead of backslash but the drive letters are still a major difference.  Other O/S use different schemes: the DEC [VMS file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files-11) was one notable example, but PrimOS used `>` instead of slash or backslash to separate pathname components, too.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my use of errno to test if fopen() worked successfully,instead of "if(pFile==NULL)" unwise?

From *7.5 Errors/3* of the C99 standard:

> The value of errno is zero at program startup, but is never set to zero by any library function.159) **The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error**, provided the use of errno is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard.

So checking `errno` to determine success or failure of an operation is unwise as a function is permitted to, pessimistically, set the value of `errno` to indicate failure, even if there is none. Only query `errno` if a function fails (if `fopen()` returns  `NULL` or `fputc()` returns `EOF` for example).

Comment: `.....In fact, if this variable is intended to be used for error checking after a library function call, it should be reset by the program to zero before the call....`    http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507974/can-or-cant-errno-be-set-to-zero-by-a-library-function-user-functionive-con

Comment: Thanks for the quote from the standard itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just looked into the manual pages to confirm that valid error numbers are all nonzero; `errno` is never set to zero by any system call or library function.

Check [the Linux `errno.h` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html):
I believe you should look at return value and then look at `errno`.